# Don't want to refresh tabsactivity when call from activity android

Tags: android, tabs, fragment

I am trying to stop refreshing my tabs activity, in the below pictures, you can see when I start new activity from tab fragment and then close it by pressing back button and returning to the tabs activity, all tabs will be restarted. I need to somehow resume tabs activity,

In the codes below, I call new activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, New_Activity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

and close it in this way:

```
finish();
```

[image: Here my all flow of calling activity and tabsactivity]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of finish just use flag for it like this way

```
Intent intent = new Intent(current_context, destination_activity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```