# Prevent reloading activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, refresh, reload, android-fragmentactivity

My problem is almost same like

[Similar Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053015/dont-want-to-refresh-tabsactivity-when-call-from-activity-android)

But the solution didn't work for me.

In my two different app I am using same menu class file but they are showing different result. I have set menu in which clicking one of the items directs toward "AboutActivity" . When in one app I back from the menu's "AboutActivity"  it refreshes the "MainActivity" but in another doesn't. The difference between the two apps is first one has two activity's (Main+About) and second one has five activity's (Main+About+Main2+Main3+..)

The code I have used in the Manifest.

```
     <activity android:name="school.infinity.maruf.agecalculator.about"
        android:label="About"
        android:parentActivityName="school.infinity.maruf.agecalculator.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|touchscreen"/>
```

This is the code used in class file

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // User clicked on a menu option in the app bar overflow menu
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.about:

            Intent intent=new Intent(this,about.class);
            startActivity(intent);
       return true;
}
```

I have used the following code for MainActivity in the manifest

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|touchscreen"/>
```

**Now how can I stop reloading/refreshing the main activity during getting back from "AboutLayout"?**

Comment: You should stop trying to avoid it and instead embrace it. Learn how the activity lifecycle works, learn how to save instance state / recover from the OS killing your process, and delete the `configChanges` attribute from your manifest.

Comment: I need it actually, otherwise user needs to input again. Moreover, in another app it is working fine, what's the issue? I don't understand.

Comment: You may not believe me, and it may not be an answer to _why_ this is happening, but I assure you that if you correctly handle the activity lifecycle and save your activity's instance state you will not have to worry about problems like this. It's worth learning.

Comment: That means is it occurring due to several Linear,Relative,Scroll layout and weight distribution in my app? I have find out a alternative trick.

=== public void onBackPressed(){
        finish();
  
        }==  using this fulfills my need when i use the bottom back key instead of top return key.